# x509 Certificate verification Python

Tags: python, cryptography, x509certificate, x509, public-key

I am trying to implement x509 certificate verification with python. Basically I just want to generate public key, private key, then a certificate using the private key. Then I want to verify that certificate with the public key and get true/false. I got the code of the key and certificate generation from this [here](https://gist.github.com/major/8ac9f98ae8b07f46b208). And the code inside try from [here](https://github.com/river2sea/X509Validation/blob/master/test/x509Validation/ValidationTest.py) (there is a verifySignature function). Here is my whole code

```
    #verify csr pem using public and private key
import random
from OpenSSL import crypto
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
import datetime
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
import uuid
from cryptography import *
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding import PKCS1v15
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature

one_day = datetime.timedelta(1, 0, 0)
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
public_key = private_key.public_key()
builder = x509.CertificateBuilder()
builder = builder.subject_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'openstack-ansible Test CA'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATION_NAME, u'openstack-ansible'),
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.ORGANIZATIONAL_UNIT_NAME, u'Default CA Deployment'),
]))
builder = builder.issuer_name(x509.Name([
    x509.NameAttribute(NameOID.COMMON_NAME, u'openstack-ansible Test CA'),
]))
builder = builder.not_valid_before(datetime.datetime.today() - one_day)
builder = builder.not_valid_after(datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2))
builder = builder.serial_number(int(uuid.uuid4()))
builder = builder.public_key(public_key)
builder = builder.add_extension(
    x509.BasicConstraints(ca=True, path_length=None), critical=True,
)
certificate = builder.sign(
    private_key=private_key, algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
    backend=default_backend()
)
print(isinstance(certificate, x509.Certificate))

with open("ca.key", "wb") as f:
    f.write(private_key.private_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
        encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b"openstack-ansible")
    ))

with open("ca.crt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(certificate.public_bytes(
        encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    ))
try:
    issuerPublicKey = public_key
    hashAlgorithm = hashes.SHA256()
    tbsCertificate = certificate.tbs_certificate_bytes
    subjectSignature = certificate.signature
    padding = PKCS1v15()
    print(issuerPublicKey.verify( subjectSignature,tbsCertificate, padding, hashAlgorithm ))
    verifier = issuerPublicKey.verify( subjectSignature,tbsCertificate, padding, hashAlgorithm )
    # verifier.update( tbsCertificate )
    verifier.verify()
    print("true")
except InvalidSignature as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Implementing your own cryptography modules is considered dangerous (even for the best programmers) from a security perspective due to implementation details. Why do you want to develop your own verifier?

Comment: oh its for a research project. Its just a demo to convey the idea of feasibility. Kind of like a MVP

Comment: What's your question precisely?

Comment: i want to generate public and private key and a certificate. Then I want to use the public key to verify the certificate. I just want to get a true/false

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you're trying to print a `None` value (which is what verify returns).

The following `verify_self_signed_x509_certificate` function will call everything the correct way in order to return a `bool` whether the certificate was self signed correctly or not

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import RSAPublicKey

def verify_self_signed_x509_certificate(public_certificate: x509.Certificate) -> bool:
    return verify_external_signed_x509_certificate(public_certificate, public_certificate)

def verify_external_signed_x509_certificate(public_certificate: x509.Certificate, parent_certificate: x509.Certificate) -> bool:

    tbs_certificate_bytes = public_certificate.tbs_certificate_bytes
    signature = public_certificate.signature
    pad = padding.PKCS1v15()

    parent_public_key = parent_certificate.public_key()
    if not isinstance(parent_public_key, RSAPublicKey):
        raise Exception('Key is not an RSA public key')
    
    try:
        parent_public_key.verify(
            signature,
            tbs_certificate_bytes,
            pad,
            hashes.SHA256()
        )
        return True
    except:
        return False
```